# SSH through VPN Chromebook

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, chromebook, crouton

So, my issue is that I have a Chromebook with crouton running on it. I've been using a browser extension to connect to a pre-set VPN to avoid any network's  filters. But, two things are happening that I'm not sure how to get around/handle.

1. The extension only tunnels traffic from the browser, and not external applications/processes.
2. If I enable the extension on chrome in the ChromeOS environment, it works in that environment but not the Ubuntu one, and vice-versa (so each environment has its own separate instance).

My main issue is the first point because I want to use SSH to connect to my VPS because I can't do it normally on a network that I use a lot (and I really don't want to use a mobile hotspot.) I included the second point because I'm not sure which environment I should let handle the network settings with VPN tunneling or if they even conflict at all.

Overall, I just want to find a way to get around network filters to connect via SSH to my VPS. This can be through a desktop client or custom configurations, but I would prefer to not set up my own VPN server. I'd like to be able to do something along the same lines as using a pre-set one like in the Chrome extension. I have Ubuntu 14.04 with the Unity desktop environment installed.

**UPDATE**: I have included the output of `nmap -p 22 -sT vps.example` (the `vps.example` line is to hide my actual VPS server. I'm not actually typing `vps.example`.) :

```
Nmap scan report for jp.jp (vps.example)
Host is up (0.0036s latency).
PORT    STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp  filtered ssh

Nmap done: 1 IP Address (1 host up) scanned in 0.26 seconds
```

Comment: What type of "VPN" are we talking about? Since you mention SSH I suspect it might be a SOCKS proxy over SSH? If you don't know, could you tell us which browser add-on you're using and with what configuration (except authentication credentials obviously). Maybe that allows us to find out the VPN type and how to set up system wide access to that VPN connection.

Comment: IMHO, If you solved your original issue (in update2) you should write it up as an answer so that others with that issue can resolve it. Your update3 belongs in a different Q&A

Comment: @ElderGeek So, would I edit out the 3rd update and move it to another SE  site and then add the 2nd update as an answer here?

Comment: @DavidFoerster The VPN browser add-on I'm using currently is [DotVPN](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dotvpn-%E2%80%94-a-better-way-to/kpiecbcckbofpmkkkdibbllpinceiihk?hl=en), but I have used [UltraSurf](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ultrasurf-security-privac/mjnbclmflcpookeapghfhapeffmpodij?hl=en-US) which ended with the same result.

Comment: @OwenHines I didn't intend to  suggest moving the 3rd update to a different site (that's your call) but this being a Q&A site where answering your own questions is indeed encouraged it helps to keep the question and answer portions separate. Due to the fact that it is more likely that someone will experience one of the issues that you came across rather than both I suggested the separation on this post. I hope this clears up any confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I achieved the result I was looking for by changing the SSH port to 443 (SSL Port.) Most, if not all, networks have that port unblocked. To do this, edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` as root. Change the line that says

`port 22`

to

`port 443`

and finally, restart the SSH service by doing

`sudo service ssh restart`

To connect to your SSH server with the new port, just add the `-p` argument and specify `443`

`ssh -p 443 user@example.com`

Some tips from [David Foerster](https://askubuntu.com/users/175814/david-foerster)

> If you don't want to type `-p 443` for that server all the time to establish an SSH connection from the command-line, you can add an entry to your `~/.ssh/config` for that host [like so](https://paste.ubuntu.com/23389311/). The `User` entry is optional but it would save you from entering the username as well. You can also specify things like dynamic and static port forwarding.

*Warning:* Keep in mind that if you have a web server running, then the SSL for it will be unable to connect to the port, so don't do this if you need to keep a web server running.

More about [SSL and port 443](http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/itanswers/what-is-port-443-why-do-ssl-vpns-make-use-of-it/)